# Powershell: How to copy a file from TFS to a different destination

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, copy-item

I'm writing a powershell script for deployment. I need to copy changed files from TFS to our Test Server. I have been able to retrieve the change sets, and I have been able to drill down to the Item. I have access to the path of the source file.

Does anyone know an efficiect way of doing this? Do I need to use the `DownloadFile` cmdlet or can I just use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

path of sourcefile is `$file.ServerItem` which resolves to, for example, `$/Project/PromonetBaseline/Main/Source/ItemHierarchy.vb`

Destination is a path like `\\104Server\WebApps\PromonetBaseline\Main\Source\ItemHierarchy.vb`

Is there a neat way to do this programatically?

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
Akin

Comment: Also, if the file exists in the detination folder, will the existing file be overwritten using the Copy-item command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I would set up a local workfold mapping for the source files, get those files and then use `Copy-Item` to copy the source files to the destination folder.  You can use the `-Force` parameter on `Copy-Item` to overwrite an existing file.

Another option is to use `tf view itemspec /i > tempfilename` to get the files from the server without creating a local workfold mapping.

Comment: I have been able to get all the changed files already, but copying it over now is what I'm not sure of. I am new to Powershell, and want to know the syntax that will work for my case

Comment: @AkinOkunrinboye Using `Copy-File` is pretty simple - `Copy-File srcpath destpath Force`.

Comment: Sounds good. Playing with it already. Thanks for your response. Good to know -Force will overwrite the existing file. :)